# Navigation bar is hiding on swipe and scroll

Tags: ios, swift

I am customising navigation bar this way in swift

```
navigationItem.title = "SUPPORT"            
let menuButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "menuIcon"), style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "showMenu:")
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = menuButton
self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated:false)
```

I am customising navigation item in all view controller and table view controller. My problem is navigation is hiding when I swipe in any view controller or scroll in table view controller. How to fix navigation bar being hidden on swipe and scroll means it should not be hidden everytime.

Answer (score 0):

add this to your root view controller ( of navigation controller )

```
self.navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = false
```